# What am I doing wrong with the styling in this sharepoint masterpage?

Tags: css, sharepoint

Here is the code sample

```
 <div class="Layouts">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Center" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server" /> 
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

The CSS that styles the Layouts div is

```
.Layouts
{
    background-color: White;
    margin-top: 17px;    
    padding-top: 18px;
}
```

Nothing to crazy there!
The problem I am having is that without the "`<p>&nbsp;</p>`" the white background does not fill down behind whatever I put in the two ContentPlaceHolders (and no they don't have an over riding background!)

With the `<p>&nbsp;</p>` it all works as I wish... but not as I expect!

Am I doing something wrong or is it a browser or a Sharepoint issue? Is there a better fix than the space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the `ContentPlaceHolder`'s floated?

If so, try adding: `overflow:hidden;` to the `.Layouts` selector.

Comment: Now the next question is how could I have found that out for myself?